# How to clear or stop muliple timeInterval in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have list of rows say multiple button name Retry in view, after clicking on Retry button it's calling angular $interval, I have called one API inside $interval, when retryCount is 4 I want to stop $interval, this is not single $interval called , it's multiple $interval called, my code is only working for single click of Retry button, if i clicked multiple Retry button , $interval stopped is not working

```
self.retryJob = function (jobId,row) {
            row.submitButtonText = "Retrying..";  
            JobService.submitJob(jobId).then(function (res) {
                if(!res.data.error){
                    row.status = "retrying";
                    row.retryCount = 0;
                    row.submitButtonText = "Retry"
                    //$scope.stop();
                    promise = $interval(function() {
                                $scope.refreshItems(jobId,row);
                              },1000);
                }else{
                    row.submitButtonText = "Error:Try Again";
                }
            }).catch(function (err) {

            });
        };
        $scope.refreshItems = function(jobId,row){
            JobService.getJobById(jobId).then(function (res) {
                console.log("res is ",res.data);
                if(!res.data.error){
                    row.status = res.data.status;
                    row.retryCount = res.data.retryCount;
                    //console.log("res.data.status="+jobId,res.data.status);
                    if(res.data.retryCount=="4" && (res.data.jobId==jobId)){
                        console.log("stoped api call");
                        //// Not working need to modify later
                        //$scope.stop();
                        $interval.cancel(promise);
                    }
                }else{
                }
            }).catch(function (err) {
                //row.killButtonText = "Error:Try Again";
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
self.retryJob = function (jobId,row) {
        row.submitButtonText = "Retrying..";  
        JobService.submitJob(jobId).then(function (res) {
            if(!res.data.error){
                row.status = "retrying";
                row.retryCount = 0;
                row.submitButtonText = "Retry"
                //$scope.stop();
                $rootScope.promise = $interval(function() {
                            $scope.refreshItems(jobId,row);
                          },1000);
            }else{
                row.submitButtonText = "Error:Try Again";
            }
        }).catch(function (err) {

        });
    };
    $scope.refreshItems = function(jobId,row){
        JobService.getJobById(jobId).then(function (res) {
            console.log("res is ",res.data);
            if(!res.data.error){
                row.status = res.data.status;
                row.retryCount = res.data.retryCount;
                //console.log("res.data.status="+jobId,res.data.status);
                if(res.data.retryCount=="4" && (res.data.jobId==jobId)){
                    console.log("stoped api call");
                    //// Not working need to modify later
                    //$scope.stop();
                    $interval.cancel($rootScope.promise);
                }
            }else{
            }
        }).catch(function (err) {
            //row.killButtonText = "Error:Try Again";
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer might depend on what your JobService is doing & returning, but still, this might do the trick:

```
    self.retryJob = function (jobId,row) {
        row.submitButtonText = "Retrying..";  
        JobService.submitJob(jobId).then(function (res) {
            if(!res.data.error){
                row.status = "retrying";
                row.retryCount = 0;
                row.submitButtonText = "Retry"
                //$scope.stop();
                var o = {};
                o.interval = $interval(function() {
                            $scope.refreshItems(jobId,row,o);
                          },1000);
            }else{
                row.submitButtonText = "Error:Try Again";
            }
        }).catch(function (err) {

        });
    };
    $scope.refreshItems = function(jobId,row,o){
        JobService.getJobById(jobId).then(function (res) {
            console.log("res is ",res.data);
            if(!res.data.error){
                row.status = res.data.status;
                row.retryCount = res.data.retryCount;
                //console.log("res.data.status="+jobId,res.data.status);
                if(res.data.retryCount=="4" && (res.data.jobId==jobId)){
                    console.log("stoped api call");
                    //// Not working need to modify later
                    //$scope.stop();
                    $interval.cancel(o.interval);
                }
            }else{
            }
        }).catch(function (err) {
            //row.killButtonText = "Error:Try Again";
        })
    }
```